# pouchdb error "no database open" while starting replication

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

i had created application using ionic and pouchdb.

i am using couchdb on my local server.

My sample application is working fine in ios and android. But same application in blackberry10 giving error while start replication

error as following

```
{
  "status": 500,
  "name": "Error",
  "message": "unknown",
  "error": "true",
  "reason": "database not open"
}
```

I had also created app to test pouchdb working in blackberry10 or not?  But it working.

so i am getting error while replication in blackberry10 application.

and i am unable to figure out why it is only giving error in blackberry10 and what is exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for response nlawson

I solved it.

I was using sqlite plugin to use websql adapter and provide size to database.

```
var localDB = new PouchDB(databaseName, {adapter: 'websql',size:10});
```

so sqlite plugin is working properly with ios and android.

i just remove sqlite plugin and make

```
var localDB = new PouchDB(databaseName);
```

and it start working on blackberry10 device.

Comment: Ah yeah, I don't believe the [SQLite Plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) supports BlackBerry. That explains it!

Answer (score 0):

We're working on BlackBerry support, but it seems like their implementation of WebSQL is not correct: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/pull/3737